# Explanation of bulls and cows algorithm in leetcode

Tags: java, algorithm

The algorithm is here: https://discuss.leetcode.com/topic/28463/one-pass-java-solution.

```
public static String getHint(String secret, String guess) {
        int bulls = 0;
        int cows = 0;
        int[] numbers = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i<secret.length(); i++) {
            int s = Character.getNumericValue(secret.charAt(i));
            int g = Character.getNumericValue(guess.charAt(i));
            if (s == g) bulls++;
            else {
                if (numbers[s] < 0){
                    cows++;
                }
                if (numbers[g] > 0){
                    cows++;
                }
                numbers[s] ++;
                numbers[g] --;
            }
        }
        return bulls + "A" + cows + "B";
    }
```

But how to understand this part:

```
numbers[s] ++;
numbers[g] --;
```

Why does it use negative number to count occurrences in guess and positive number to count in secret.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [++i, i++ pre/post incrementation usage with arrays in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39809772/i-i-pre-post-incrementation-usage-with-arrays-in-java)

Comment: I have no problem to understand the ++i/i++ operator. The point is here why increment in 'secret' and decrease in 'guess'.

Comment: if you have confusion about some part in algorithm then it would be better to state it explicitly because `But how to understand this part:` seems like a question answered in the duplicate

Comment: I revised the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `numbers` array keeps track of the ***unmatched*** numbers seen in the two arrays. Initially each entry in the `numbers` array is 0, indicating that number has not been seen in either array. A positive entry means that the number was seen in the `secret` array more times than in the `guess` array. A negative entry means the number was seen in the `guess` array more times than in the `secret` array.

So when the algorithm sees a number in the `secret` array, it increases the corresponding entry in the `numbers` array. If that entry happened to be negative before the increment, it means that the number was already seen in the `guess` array, so the `cows` count is increased.

Likewise when the algorithm sees a number in the `guess` array, it decreases the corresponding entry in the `numbers` array. If that entry happened to be positive before the decrement, it means that the number was already seen in the `secret` array, so the `cows` count is increased.